# Moving/animating UI Elements in iOS with a gesture

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, ios7

I have created a custom TabView as I needed to do things the native class couldn't. It is basically just a collection of UIButtons. I want to set it up so that with a gesture the TabBar animates in/out of the screen so that it can be hidden. I am just not exactly sure how to do it. My first thought was to simply move the frame with a loop, but I have found methods like CGAffineTransform which seems like that is what it is there for. I am also afraid I am over complicating it and there is a simple solution I haven't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using frames or constraints?

An easier way to animate with frames

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{ enter new frame position}];
```

Or if you're using constraints update the constraint constant and then call

`[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{ [view setNeedsLayout]}];`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew I was over thinking it! Thanks!